# Flutter windows on lower resolution and Higher resolution design got Disturb How to manage it on system for web and desktop both

Tags: flutter, dart

- recently i found that when we change in resolution or changing the screen resolution percentage it will reflact on site or desktop UI not showing like we need
- i need same UI for all resolution

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: IT DOESN'T NEED A CODE YOU CAN TRY IT BY RUN THE FLUTTER WEB THEN CHANGE THE RESOLUTION AND SHOW THE FLUTTER WEB IT WILL NOT SHOWING AS WE EXPECT OR YOU CAN ALSO CHANGE THE SCALE 100% TO 150%